# How to mock UUID class in Scala?

Tags: scala, mocking

I am trying to mock `UUID.randomUUID().toString` in Scala. How do I do it?

I tried couple of ways but did not work.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that "did not work". It can be helpful in understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are looking to `mock` a static function... Java people use `powermock` for this purpose... but making powermock work with Scala tests is not an easy task. 
One workaround is to wrap such static methods in your own Scala methods and use them in your code. Then you just mock your own scala wrapper methods.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Structure your code somewhat like this:

```
import java.util.UUID

trait UUIDGenerator {
  def apply(): String
}

object UUIDGenerator {
  object Live extends UUIDGenerator {
    override def apply(): String = UUID.randomUUID().toString
  }
}
```

Then in your tests do:

```
val stubbedUUIDGenerator: UUIDGenerator = () => new UUID(0,0).toString
```